# randomize multiple materials to different objects

Tags: materials

I found  a nice tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6o3Dq6bkn8&list=PL8iHMWPijQzs7RqTZDcXx7mtjMMTKk5es&index=116&ab_channel=Blender

this is to randomise material according a prefix name  , so you can take a several materials starting with the same prefix  and  apply  them randomly to several meshes.

how could I apply this script  if each mesh use a different prefix.
if I have 2 objects and I want to randomise 1 with a prefix  and randomise the second one with another prefix in the same script.

I don't know anything about python

```
import random
import bpy

prefix = '_'

materials = []
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
     if mat.name.startswith(prefix):
         materials.append(mat)

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     obj.active_material = random.choice(materials)
```

here is the python script  on the youtube tutorial

If anyone has a solution , that ll be great

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of prefixes and use a loop to check against them all.  (There are other ways but this is easy to explain.)  Here's your loop modified:

```
import random
import bpy

prefixes = ['_', '.']

materials = []
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    for prefix in prefixes:
         if mat.name.startswith(prefix):
             materials.append(mat)

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     obj.active_material = random.choice(materials)
```

You can have as many prefixes in the list on the 4th line as you'd like. You just have to make sure each one is unique.

I used a period in my example.  Replace it with whatever you want for your second prefix.

Comment: Thanks! it works great  with material with different prefixes to use them randomly,  actually I try for exemple having materials on prefix A and materials on prefix B, to assign one object the A and the other object the B only, here it's mixing both, may be  my question wasnt clear enough, sorry

Comment: No need to apologize. Perhaps I didn't understand the question.  Do you mean you want two lists, one for object A and the other for object B based on prefixes?  So any material that starts '_' could be used for the first object, and any material that starts '.' could be used for the second?

Comment: exactly, to be more clear and explain the idea behind this, I want to swap some haircut , so A would be for hairstyle bottom head , and  B tophead. That would use the materials  with prefixes.  , but I don't want to  play 2 scripts  for each plane just one, so it combines randomly different haircut. may be I,m getting too specific, but i think a sketch could be better than words , here is a link https://imgur.com/YkeIpEI